# SlowCheetah transforms "patch" to "x"

Tags: .net, slowcheetah

I have a config override using SlowCheetah that is completely empty of override rules. However, when I preview the transform file I see that it replaces an element called `<patch:attribute .... />` to `<x:attribute ..../>`.

[image]

It does the same when building both locally and using TeamCity, so it's not a preview bug.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance.